Convert a string to base 64 using T-SQL
I'm having the issue while converting the string to base 64 for encoding using T-SQL. As I use chatgpt to search and some function like
SELECT BASE64_ENCODE (CAST ('hello world' AS varbinary))

SELECT CAST('string' AS varbinary(max)) 
FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64

After that I test with a function using C# as:
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded)

However, it returns the undesired result. For example, I have a string ABCD and when using the above methods to convert it into Base64 in SQL with the above methods it returns as QQBCAEMARAA=, in which will return as A�B�C�D� for me later by the decode function while testing with Postman.
So in here I want the string ABCD to be converted into QUJDRAo= according to https://www.base64encode.org/, does anyone know to deal with this issue ?

It helps if you use the right data type, and encoding, for your string. Windows-1252 <> UTF-16: db<>fiddle

I also assume CrapGPT was not kind enough to vomit out words to tell you BASE64_ENCODE is currently only available in Azure solutions, not on premises.

Why do you need to do this in SQL though, especially since you mention postman, which i'm guessing doesn't call the database directly

Also varbinary or varchar without a length, don't ever do this.

It looks like you currently have an nvarchar string so when you convert it to binary it is using UCS-2 encoding whereas the C# is trying to decode it as UTF8.
You can cast it to varchar with a UTF8 collation before casting to binary to get your expected result.
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ABCD'

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @string collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8)
              ) 
        FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64


Your issue is not about Base64 conversion, but about representation of strings. Your string is being created as Unicode. When passed to the base64 encode, it's still Unicode i.e. a sequence of 16-bit characters. The C# decode is restoring the data to an array of bytes which would be correctly interpreted as a sequence of 16-bit characters, except that the UTF8.GetString is interpreting the byte array as a sequence of 8-bit characters.
It appears that you want the base64 to represent a UTF-8 string, so you need to ensure that your string is UTF8 before you encode to base64.
